# Select property by lambda by PropertyInfo variable

Tags: c#

This is my POCO object:

```
public class ExampleTestOfDataTypes
{
    public float FloatProp { get; set; }
    public BoolWrapper BoolProp2 { get; set; }
}
```

This is configuration file of the POCO

```
public class ExampleTestOfDataTypesConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<ExampleTestOfDataTypes>
{
    public ExampleTestOfDataTypesConfig()
    {    
         this.Property(x=>x.FloatProp).HasColumnName("CustomColumnName");
    }
}
```

This is definition of EntityTypeConfiguration (the property configuration is just for example)

```
ExampleTestOfDataTypesConfig config = new ExampleTestOfDataTypesConfig();
```

I need to go through all the properties of class ExampleTestOfDataTypes, find all the properties which dataTypes are derived from Wrapper (BoolWrapper is) and then get these properties using lambda expression. Or anyhow select them by config.Property(...)

```
Type configPocoType = config.GetType().BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
var poco = Activator.CreateInstance(configPocoType);

foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property in poco.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    if (property.PropertyType.BaseType!=null&&
        property.PropertyType.BaseType == typeof(Wrapper)
        )
    {
        //TODO: Set property
        //config.Property(x=>x.[What here]); //?
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

### Update

I didn't notice that the `Property` method is not your own implementation, sorry. It looks like you have to create an expression manually. This should work, or at least be close enough:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(configPocoType);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(
    Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property),
    parameter);

config.Property(lambda);
```

### Original answer

It looks pretty likely that your existing `Property` method just uses an `Expression` to read the name of the property while maintaining compile-time safety. Most of the time such methods use reflection to pull out the property name into a string and then go on reflecting using the string name (possibly by calling another overload of `Property` that accepts a string).

Therefore, a reasonable approach is to invoke this other overload yourself, since your code already has a `PropertyInfo` in hand from which you can immediately get the property name.

If you only have one `Property` method, refactor by splitting it into two parts: one that pulls the name out of the `Expression` and one that works with the name; you can then call the second directly from your code.

Comment: Thanks... could you please give me a little more help? The Property methods return type is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.primitivepropertyconfiguration%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

Comment: @VojtěchBašta: Doesn't matter what the return is really, but you need to post the code for `Property` (at least the part in the beginning).

Comment: i am sorry i probably did not understand you correctly. The problem is that i cannot post here the code of Property () because it is in assembly of EntityFramework. And i don't know how to write override method with return type that i cannot get (or to be more precised it has no constructor no public properties to set... so i cannot take the method create new instance of the PrimitivePropertyConfiguration with PropertyInfo of required property...)

Comment: @VojtěchBašta: Sorry, didn't notice it was not your own code. See updated answer.